# Search component in react using static contextTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-component

So far this is my search component

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Search extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  searchRef = React.createRef();

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = this.searchRef.current.value;
    // get the value of that input
    this.context.router.history.push(`/search/${searchTerm}`);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={this.searchRef}
            placeholder="Hoppy"
            //assign that ref to a DOM node
          />
          <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

What I want to do is to use the  `push` method to update the browser's URL
but the error I get:

> Warning: Failed context type: The context `router` is marked as
>   required in `Search`, but its value is `undefined`.

I have googled the error and most people say it's because of a certain version of react-router but when I use a different version it makes no difference, how can I solve this problem? Can someone show me an example ?

Comment: which version of react-router are you using. Its better if you actually update it to the latest version

Comment: You are using old react API (context). And you have to be sure to use appropriate version of libraries. Also check react-router provider, did you register it?

Comment: I have the version reat router dom 4.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using v4 of react-router, you no longer needs to access the router from context. You can access them via props

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Search extends React.Component {

  searchRef = React.createRef();

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = this.searchRef.current.value;
    // get the value of that input
    this.props.history.push(`/search/${searchTerm}`);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={this.searchRef}
            placeholder="Hoppy"
            //assign that ref to a DOM node
          />
          <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Also make sure that Search is rendered by route like

```
<Route path="/somesearchpath" component={Search} />
```

If search is not a direct child of Route, you need to make use of `withRouter` to wrap the Search in order to use Router props

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';


...


export default withRouter(Search);
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion but now i get this error ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

In order to let react router to inject its API to your component, you need to wrap the `<Search />` component with react-router's context component - `<Router />`

Like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";


<Router>
  <Search />
</Router>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-4-class-component-example-pi4v1